# Adding a border is causing my header format to have issues

Tags: html, css, html-lists, border

I am trying to add a border to my header, but when I do, the line-height (or something like that) is getting messed up.

**HTML** -

```
<div class='header'>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Estimates</li>
    <li>Co2 Calculator</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS** -

```
.header {
    background-color: #006633;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

ul.headerlist {
    line-height: 50px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Is it something to do with using `<ul>` or `<li>`?

Comment: what do you mean by "messed up"? Being a bit more descriptive will be more helpful in solving the issue. Even putting the code into jsFiddle might help us see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start by cleaning up you HTML structure.

1. You don't need to apply the class to all the LI's since they're all
   the same.
2. Apply the block of CSS you had for .header to the ul instead
3. Use line-height that measures the height of the ul to get the li to
   center vertically.

```css
.header {
  /* do whatever you want with the header */
  width: 100%; /* Adjust as needed */
  height: auto;
  }

.header ul {
background-color: #006633;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid gray;
  display: block;
}
.header li {
width: 19%;
text-align: center;
color: white;
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
    <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Services</li>
                    <li>Estimates</li>
                    <li>Co2 Calculator</li>
                    <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.header ul{margin-top:0;} There you go.

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m71mchow/14/
and add this css :

```
ul, li{margin:0; padding:0}
```